# Intent problem: how to use MainActivity from another class "Adapter" to pass data to SecondActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-adapter

This is in Adapter.Java

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String name=listItemData.get(i).getName();
        Intent intent = Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("NAME", name);
    }
```

I have now idea how to use MainActivity.this when I'm not in MainActivity class..

Comment: why do you need `MainActivity` context  to send data to `SecondActivity` from `Adapter` ? please update your question and explain what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

**Solution 1**

You have to pass `context` while you initialized Adapter in `MainActivity`.

In `MainActivity.this`:

```
XyzAdapter adapter = new XyzAdapter(MainActivity.this, .. ..)
```

In your `Adapter`:

```
private Context mContext;
   public XyzAdapter(Context context .. ..){
      mContext = context;
   }
```

And then you can do like below:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        String name=listItemData.get(i).getName();
        Intent intent = Intent(mContext, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("NAME", name);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**Solution 2**

Another option is `interface`

Create one `interface` like below:

```
public interface AdapterInterface {
        public void buttonPressed();
    }
```

Now in your adapter:

```
AdapterInterface buttonListener;
public XyzAdapter(Context context, AdapterInterface buttonListener)
{
  super(context,c,flags);
  this.buttonListener = buttonListener;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
      buttonListener.buttonPressed()
}
```

In your `Activity`:

```
AdapterInterface buttonListener;
public MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity implements AdapterInterface{
```

in `onCreate`

```
buttonListener = this;

XyzAdapter adapter = new XyzAdapter(MainActivity.this, buttonListener  .. ..)



@Override
public void buttonPressed(){
  // here you have to do once your click perform
}
```

Comment: Solution 1 was closest to what I did. 
I also had to add this to make it work:
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: you can also use solution 2 if you pass one an argument as a sting in interface.
you have to pass string in interface that you get in activity.

use of this same things you can do at activity,

Answer (score 0):

You can have a member variable of type `Activity` in your Adapter class (e.g. `private Activity mActivity;`) and pass your MainActivity instance to your Adapter class in the constructor of your Adapter class and assign it to `mActivity`. Some thing like this:

```
public Adapter(Activity activity) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
}
```

Then in your `onClick` method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String name=listItemData.get(i).getName();
    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("NAME", name);
    mActivity.startActivity(intent);
}
```